# How do I get rid of the three small dots in a split-pane-divider within a pane-divider in JavaFX 2?

Tags: css, styles, javafx

I am working in a style sheet, I had no major problems with styling until now. I need to remove the three little dots in the middle of the split-pane-divider.

I found no information about those three dots in the [JavaFX Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#splitpane).

I cant upload a picture to make it clearer, with the resources found on the reference guide I managed to change the background color, borders, and orientation, but the small dots in the enter remain there.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same question here!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `caspian.css` file in the `jfxrt.jar`

Maybe you see there how they styled the `split-pane-divider` and then you could override it.

**Edit:**

The OP suggests now the following solution:

```
.split-pane *.horizontal-grabber {-fx-background-color: transparent, transparent;}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2290698